# What is difference between expressions of $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus

I want to ask about expression $\frac{dy}{dx}$ that applies to instantaneous velocity and average rate of change.

because I thought I can figure it out but I wasn't able to. Also I asked to professor but he gave me simple answer of how to solve the question.

As far as I studied till now, Average rate of change is a literally average velocity between two points, $\frac {f(b)-f(a)} {b-a}$.

And If we take the limit of average rate of change, We can get instantaneous velocity at the certain point,which we can write as $$\lim_ 
 {h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{ h}$$. Also this can be expressed as $\frac{dy}{dx}$. literally (changes of y values)/( changes of x values).

apart from It's formula, I know average rate of change is different from instantaneous velocity. Average rate of change is literally how much you go per hours, mins or secs, likewise How It is written. Instantaneous veolcity is a velocity of certain moment lies upon the interval. so you can get how much fast you are at that vary moment.

what is between those 2 expression of $\frac{dy}{dx}$? average rate of change and instantaneous velocity is clearly different but expressed as same way, so how can you tell between them when somebody just give you $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of something? It could be average rate of change or instantaneous velocity.

Thank you! I really wanted to ask this!

Comment: See [Differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_(mathematics)#Introduction) and see [Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If the function used is $f$, then its derivative will be $\dfrac {df}{dx}$. More specifically, if the function velocity is a function defined as $v=\dfrac s t$, then [Instantaneous velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity#Equation_of_motion) will be $v= \dfrac {ds}{dt}$.

Comment: $\dfrac {ds}{dt}$ is instantaneous, while average is $\dfrac {\Delta s}{\Delta t}$.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is short for $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given two distinct points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$, the average velocity between these two points is defined to be $$\frac {f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

What people call the instantaneous rate of change is the limit as $b$ approaches $a$. Namely, the limit $$\lim_{b\to a}\frac {f(b)-f(a)} {b-a}$$

By making a change of variables and letting $h=b-a$, the above limit can be expressed as $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)} {h}$$

Thus the instantaneous rate of change at a point is found by picking a point far away and bringing that point near the original point. That is the idea behind taking the limit. This limit is then expressed by symbols $\frac {dy} {dx}$ or in our case it would be expressed as $\frac {df(a)} {dx}$ having the function $f$ defined in terms of the variable $x$.

There is also a geometric interpretation to this. The derivative at a point $(a, f(a))$ tells us the slope of the tangent line to the point $(a, f(a))$. Think of the function $$f(x)=x^2$$

The derivative at the point $x=1$ is $2$. Using the point-slope form equation for finding the equation of the tangent line, you will see that the line described by $$y=2x-1$$ is the tangent line to the point $(1, 1)$. Here is a picture showing the graph of the curve $x^2$ and the tangent line to the point $(1, 1)$ which was found by finding the point-slope form equation to find the tangent line.

[image]